# How to define a vector of a templated using member of a templated class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The compiler (`g++-7`) emits an error when compiling the following code:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename MetricType, typename DataType>
class Label {
  public:
    using metric_type = Label<MetricType, int>;

    template<typename LabelDataType> using label_type = Label<MetricType, LabelDataType>;
  // ...
};

template<typename LabelType>
class Raptor {
  public:
    std::vector<typename LabelType::metric_type> works;

    std::vector<typename LabelType::label_type<int> > throws_an_error;
};

int main() {
  Raptor<Label<int, int> > raptor;
  return 0;
}
```

The error message is

```
main.cpp:17:53: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     std::vector<typename LabelType::label_type<int> > throws_an_error;
                                                     ^
main.cpp:17:53: error: template argument 2 is invalid
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/bin.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/bin.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/bin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I tried giving the `std::vector` an empty struct as the second template argument, but the error message stays the same.

I have no idea what this error message means and how to make this code compile.
Especially I'm confused, because the field `works` does not produce any errors, also when commenting the errorneous field out, but the types `metric_type` and `label_type<int>` are equal.

Comment: `typename LabelType::template label_type<int>`

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you very much!